# Populate datagrid from controls selected value

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Good day, guys I have a web form with controls on the left side (text boxes, dropdown lists) and a datagridview on the right. I want to select the values from the controls on the left and with the press of a button I want to populate the datagridview on the right. (Almost like adding products to an invoice)

Comment: Okay.... And? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Break your problem into pieces... How to populate datagridview, how to do something on button click, how to do something on selection change in combobox etc.

Comment: ok sorry guys. in simple terms how do I transfer the values from the controls to the datagridview each inside its own column within the datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

try this on button click:

```
private void btnGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string message = string.Empty;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        bool isSelected = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value);
        if (isSelected)
        {
            message += Environment.NewLine;
            message += row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Selected Values" + message);
}
```